# ng-options add suffix to each option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose i have the following array with strings:

`$scope.open_slots = ["00","10","50"]`, and i would like to have the following results:

[image]

without doing this : `$scope.open_slots = ["00 minutes","10 minutes","50 minutes"]`

how can i just add suffix to each item in the select option list?

this is my code:

```
 <select data-ng-model="minutes_per_slot" data-ng-options="item for item in open_slots"></select>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using the `as` part of the `ngOptions`:

```
ng-options="slot as slot+' minutes' for slot in open_slots">
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/L1ncxwdg/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<select data-ng-model="minutes_per_slot" 
        data-ng-options="item as item + ' minutes' for item in open_slots">
```